# (ionic) How to share variables(from server) to 'search' relative pages?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

This is my task: Get search selections from server when route to a search page or it child pages (eg: #/search/option1). The problem is how to share the selections to all search relative pages and don't request server twice and don't expose selections to root scope?

I don't know weather I describe clearly, not good at it. Thanks for your reading. Appreciate any tip, any.

Comment: So what you want to do is: 1. Make a search request to a server 2. Reuse the result to avoid multiple request?

Comment: @sjokkogutten, Thanks for your reply. Yes, more than that, I want to share these result to 'search' relative pages. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the result from the server and then reuse the result throughout you application.

Create a factory (or service) that retrieves and stores the values from the server:

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var values;
  var requestValues = function() {
    $http.get("/api/getValues").then(
        function(results){
            values = results;
        });
  };
  var getValues = function() {
    return values;
  };
  return {
    requestValues : requestValues, // this will make a http request and store the result
    getValues: getValues // this will call the stored result (without making a http request)
  }
});
```

Now you have two functions in your factory.

1. `requestValues()` to make the http request and save the result locally
2. `getValues()` to get the locally saved values without making a http request.

Once `requestValues()` has been called, you should be able to call `getValues()` from anywhere to get the values without making a new http request.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, DataService) {
  var init = function (){
    DataService.requestValues(); // this will make the http request and store the result
    $scope.items = DataService.getValues(); // this will get the result
  };

  var justGetValues = function(){
    $scope.items = DataService.getValues(); // this will get the result (without making a http request)
  };    
});
```

Now you simply have to call `DataService.getValues()` whenever you need the values. (You might want to wrap these in a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). I have refrained from doing this due to simplicity)

Comment: I use another way: Wrap all relative pages to a wrapper controller and get the result at the wrapper controller. But your solution seen more reusable. Thanks for your answer!